# how to handle receipt_message in balebot

Tags: python, bots, handler, bale-messenger, balebot

I've used `balebot` and developed a shop bot with it. Now i have a problem. I need a way to check if request money was paid successfully or not. Is there any filter for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem before. After updating python balebot platform to version 1.1.3 BankMessageFilter() has been added to it.
remember Receipt message is a type of BankMessage. Here is a simple code:

```
@dispatcher.message_handler(PhotoFilter())
def purchase_message(bot, update):
    message = update.get_effective_message()
    user_peer = update.get_effective_user()
    first_purchase_message = PurchaseMessage(msg=message, account_number=6037991067471130, amount=100,
                                             money_request_type=MoneyRequestType.normal)
    bot.send_message(first_purchase_message, user_peer, success_callback=success, failure_callback=failure)
    dispatcher.register_conversation_next_step_handler(update, [MessageHandler(BankMessageFilter(), payment),
                                                                MessageHandler(DefaultFilter(), default_handler)])


def payment(bot, update):
    message = update.get_effective_message()
    print("message:", message)
    success_payment = TextMessage("Thanks, your payment was successful")
    bot.reply(update, success_payment, success_callback=success, failure_callback=failure)
    dispatcher.finish_conversation(update)
```